Two arrows touching in a technical drawing, what is it refering to?

When two arrows are touching in a technical drawing (circled in red), does that mean I should look at the next closest arrow to get the actual dimension the arrow is referring to (green dots in the drawing)?  Is this some sort of convention?

It looks wrong to me. The upper 53.90 arrow is shared between itself and the 4.85 ref. I would expect the 3.98 to be offset from the previous two to avoid confusion and a second arrow in line with that to reference the top of the tab.

A guess. 3.98 and 0.157 appear to be about half of 7.95 and 0.313 respectively.

the arrows are not touching ... there is a line between them

the colored dots have a meaning

Imo this is objectively a terrible drawing.

The "REF." dimensions indicate that the actual tolerances are being maintained in a previous operation for the part. For this drawing, only the 0.79 ±0.25 feature is being added to the part. (An electrical contact perhaps??). Note that the 3.98 dimension is 1/2 of the 7.95 tab width; the inspector can allow the tapped hole location to be measured from either side of the tab.

This is the official standard for a pcie bracket (metal thing at the end of e.g. a graphics card that is used to secure the card to the case) so that measurment is just for a nib thing that helps line it up. Didn't know about the REF thing, thanks.
